# Issue in compiling an FLTK program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fltk

I'm having some really hard times in getting to run a first simple project with FLTK. At the moment I have followed the steps on this [page](http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html)

But when I try to compile my code I still get the error :

> LNK 1104 impossible to open the file 'fltkjpegd.lib'.

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `fltk` libraries dependencies to your Visual Studio project as is described [here](https://bewuethr.github.io/installing-fltk-133-under-visual-studio/)

Comment: Just make sure you only add the d.lib versions for the debug build and the non d.lib versions for the release build.